# Oracle partition by

Tags: sql, oracle10g, window-functions

I have been trying to understand the over partition by function present in SQL, as I have wrote a query based on some parameters for which I'm getting multiple records for same id's. They query which I wrote was skeptically to fetch a person's details like his name, dob, address and more.. In this case I'm getting multiple records as the address of the user is more then one. For now I'm taking the preferred address, but it may happen that there ain't any preferred address for the user, so I won't get that person's details even if it matches to my given parameters. So I think I will have to use this so called over partition by such that I get 1 address per user.

My condition : if the person has a preferred address then I will choose that, or else I will choose any of the mentioned non preferred address. For eg, let's say that the user has a preferred address and multiple non preferred address also. So if i order my records by desc then I will take the first row which will be the preferred address as the flag is Y. Similarly, if there are only non preferred address again I will take the first row from the returned result.

I have seen multiple suggestions on this over partition by function but I can't make it work for my scenario.

So any help will be good.

Comment: please provide table schema and sample data

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example; my ADDR table (with factoring clause, actually) has 3 columns:

- EMPNO - employee number
- ADDRESS - his address
- PREF - is it a preferred address? If so, its value is "y"

---

Query "ranks" addresses per EMPNO, ordered by address preference. Have a look, adjust it so that it fits your situation.

```
SQL> with addr (empno, address, pref) as
      2    (select 1, 'manhattan 12', 'y' from dual union  --> this
      3     select 1, 'boulevard 1', 'n'  from dual union
      4     --
      5     select 2, 'thames st. 4', 'n' from dual union  --> any of
      6     select 2, 'snowy rd. 2', 'n'  from dual        --> these two
      7    ),
      8  ranks as
      9    (select empno, address, pref,
     10            row_number() over (partition by empno order by decode(pref, 'y', '0', '1'), address) rn
     11     from addr
     12    )
     13  select empno, address, pref
     14  from ranks
     15  where rn = 1;

         EMPNO ADDRESS      P
    ---------- ------------ -
             1 manhattan 12 y
             2 snowy rd. 2  n

    SQL>
```